# IE8 error object doesn't support property

Tags: jquery

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; YPC 3.2.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 26 Jul 2011 13:35:27 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 2
Char: 69242
Code: 0
URI: http://sadiecoles.uwpistol.net/CatalystScripts/Cache/lightbox2021.js
```

This is the error I keep getting from this page http://sadiecoles.uwpistol.net/CustomContentRetrieve.aspx?ID=1142452

I've recently added the jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($){ to the code I've written but I'm still getting the error in IE.

Anyone any ideas as to how to sort this? Thanks very much for all the help I get!

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

or just

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

You might have a type error or something in the data you're *sending to* jQuery. 
IE is very picky about data types, much more so than any of the other common browsers.

Also look at how you are declaring objects and arrays. IE will freak out if you use array methods on something you declared as an object.

```
var myObject = {};
var myArray = [];
```

jsLint can also help you root out stuff like this.

Comment: I'm doing jQuery.noConflict(); is this not correct? what is jsLint?

Comment: It's better to just use jQuery instead of $, or to associate jQuery.noConflict(); with a variable. jsLint validates your javascript code. this will help you identify any errors in your code which might cause an error in IE. It's picky, so it's likely to catch stuff that FF/Chrome/Safari will let slide.

Comment: Ok I've found this "Problem at line 3 character 1: 'jQuery' was used before it was defined.

jQuery.noConflict(); " What does it mean? :O

Comment: It means that you are using an object (jQuery) without having defined that object on the page. In Chrome debugger or FF firebug run   `console.log( jQuery('body') );`  What do you get? Also check that your script to load jquery comes *before* the place where you're calling jQuery.noConflict() or making any other calls to methods on the jQuery object.

Comment: You're also loading several js libraries before you're loading jquery. Are you sure none of those other libs are plugins which need jquery?

Comment: in exhibitions.js, I think I would just get rid of the jquery.noConflict(), and use a jQuery(document).ready() rather than encapsulating like you do. This will make sure that jQ is totally loaded before anything in that script executes.

Comment: ok so my console.log(jQuery('body')); results in [body] is this the desired result? what does that code do? I'm now removing noConflict and adding jQuery(document).ready() I'll let you know! Thanks so much for this help. I was lost :S

Comment: jQuery('body') just checks for a body tag in your html. But it would fail if you didn't have jQuery valid in the page. You would get an error. So the fact that it's returning the object means jQuery is loaded into the page and working.